# Google App bundle signin problems Google play console give me error

Tags: android, google-play-console

I have an old app that has been removed from the Google store. The app did not use signing through google. Now I need to upload a new version of the app, but it says I need to integrate signing apk configuration.
I have the old jks file.

Following google's directions I downloaded the public key and then generated the private key by doing:

```
java -jar pepk.jar --keystore=test.jks --alias=test --output=output.zipper --include-cert --rsa-aes-encryption --encryption-key-path=encryption_public_key.pem
```

At this point I generate a folder.zip that has a file inside called encryptedPrivateKey and a file called certificate.pem

The procedure asks me to upload the private key. I upload 'encryptedPrivateKey' it but the moment I hit save, it says: 'The key is in an incorrect format or has not been encrypted correctly'

Has anyone else had the same problem? Solutions?

It's the same if I use this option 'Use existing app signature key of Java key store' or this 'Use existing app signing key from another repository'